# Запрос на добавление записи

Tags: sql

Есть таблица partition с полями name,link,айдишник.
Айдишник при этом самозаполняющийся.

Есть запрос

```
INSERT INTO partition (name,link) VALUES ( 'имя' , '?a=index/info&partition=айдишник_этой_записи' )
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при инсерте в ссылку подставлялся правильный айдишник?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into partition (name, link)
select 'имя', '?a=index/info&partition='+ cast(max(ID)+1 as nvarchar(max))
  from partition
```

Это если рост по одному. Если по другому идет - тогда прибавляйте. Скорее всего, в 99,9% случаев сбоев с такой конструкцией не будет, но могут быть ньюансы.

Для избежания ньюансов - две транзакции, сначала делаете инсерт, потом апдейтом добавляете айдишник. Или делаете триггер на таблицу на событие "AFTER INSERT", которая будет сама добавлять айдишник в нужное поле.

Comment: Какой галочкой? Какого поля?

Comment: О, триггер подойдет, спасибо! А как он выглядеть будет примерно? А то я с триггерами дел в mysql не имел еще.

Comment: Так же, как и для остальных SQL, насколько я понимаю: делаете

INSERT INTO partition (name,link) VALUES ( 'имя' , '?a=index/info&partition=' )

И триггер будет выглядеть примерно так:

CREATE TRIGGER partition_insert AFTER INSERT ON partition
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   update partition
      set link = link + cast(id as CHAR)
    where id = NEW.id
END;

Сам с MySQL не работал, поэтому с синтаксисом могу напутать, но вроде верно

Answer (score 1):

Ну айдишник хранится в $_GET[] от туда и берите, а потом просто вставляйте в таблицу.
Честно говоря, у Вас явно не верно спроэктированно приложение. 
Я бы предложил пересмотреть его архитектуру)
З.Ы. При интерполяции строк, заключайте в двойные ковычки.

Comment: Нет, вы не поняли - до инсерта записи еще нет, значит, и ее айдишника тоже! Вопрос только в SQL запросе, РНР тут вообще не при чем.
Равно как и архитектура.

Comment: Не понимаю Вас. Вам не нужно заполнять поле ID, при добавлении новой записи оно инкриминируется

Comment: @systemiv, А что такое "интерполяция строк"?

Comment: А зачем вам хранить ссылку с айдишником в базе? Если эта часть ссылки  неизменна `?a=index/info&partition=`, а айдишник в базе уже есть, зачем хранить в базе еще иполную ссылку? Вы же всегда можете ее получить в коде программы.

Comment: При создании новой записи выбирается ее тип. Ссылка может меняться в зависимости от типа записи (информация, каталог и т.д.)

Comment: Не, все-таки тут что-то не так с архитектурой. Ссылка вообще не должна храниться. Она должна генерироваться при необходимости. А вот как раз тип записи - хранится в БД.